# Good coding practices with R: message/cat/print/warning/error?

Tags: r, printing, cat

Regarding R packages development, when the function should return an error message or a warning, what is best to use?:

- `cat()`
- `print()`
- `message()`
- `error()`
- `warning()`

For example in this function, which one should I use to return an error message when a or b are not numbers.

```
function_sum_two_nums <- function(a, b){

    ## Check if the a and b are numbers

    if(is.numeric(a) & is.numeric(b)){
        return(a+b)
    } else{
        print/cat/message/error/warning('a or b are not numbers')
    }
}
```

Comment: As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/68712477/2954547, you probably meant `stop`, not `error`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Your example

In this particular case, the only sensible option is to use `stop()`, because *this situation is an error*, and you *want to stop the function from continuing* when the error is encountered.

The other options will allow code execution to proceed, returning the last evaluated expression in the function. This is not what you want.

### In general

Use `print()` when you want to provide output for the end-user. Use `cat()` for more control over output in the same situation. This is *not* suitable for "library code", because it cannot be suppressed easily. However, it is the correct way to perform tasks like emitting data to stdout for processing in a shell pipeline, or writing functions that "pretty print" interesting things.

Use `message()` for informational messages that are not warnings or errors, but that arise during some computation where the user didn't specifically request output. For example, if you are developing a package, and you want to inform the user that they can install a special dependency to improve performance, you can use `message()` to emit this message. Messages can be suppressed by the user with `suppressMessages`.

Use `warning()` to indicate *problematic situations* that do not require function execution to abort. An example would be if the user requested an action that would be very slow, or that might cause numerical stability problems in a later computation. Warnings can be suppressed by the user with `suppressWarnings`.

As above, use `error()` when something is so totally wrong that the function cannot continue executing. Errors can be caught and handled, (e.g. with `tryCatch`), but the user must specifically make this happen.

### The technical part

The other functions: `message`, `warning`, and `stop` each signal (or "throw") a **condition**. I will not go into detail on what conditions are, because Wickham covers them in [chapter 8 of *Advanced R*](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/conditions.html).

The very simple version is the all 3 of these introduce a signal to the R runtime, that does nothing on its own. The user can then install a "handler" for a specific condition, which is a function that is invoked whenever the condition is signaled.

R has default handlers for the conditions signaled by `message()`, `warning(),` and `error()`. This is how the standard behavior of those functions is implemented.

Comment: This is a good, thorough answer.  It may be worth noting that `message()` and `warning()` can be *suppressed* by the user (via `suppressMessages()` and `suppressWarnings()`); it can be frustrating to encounter unwanted "noisy" output from  `cat()`/`print()`  (this is implicit in your comment that users can install handlers for conditions, but not obvious to less experienced users).

Comment: @BenBolker Great point, I updated my answer to include that information.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, none of your listed examples since there are functions within `base` especially for both (warning/error) cases:

- `warning('a or b are not numbers')` will result in an warning message but continue executes
- `stop('a or b are not numbers')` stops executes and throws an error

Comment: Thanks, good to know that they exit. I have edited the question accordingly since, it is not clear to me then, when to use any of the five (possibly more) options.